# Can we see more Hot Network Questions?

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

I like having **Hot Network Questions** on the right of the questions list, but could we turn the header text into a link to [here](https://stackexchange.com/questions)?

I suppose this is a very minor feature request, but it would save me a few clicks. Anybody else?

Thanks

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes it is, missed that!